# Activating Autocommit in managed transaction

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, playframework-2.2

In an application with managed context (Play!, Eclipselink) I do have a Method which uses JPA.withTransaction, but must not do a rollback. It has external communication and XML-marshalling and unmarshalling and so on, so different Exceptions may occur.

The normal behaviour of JPA.withTransaction is to rollback the current transaction on (most) Exceptions.

If such an Exception is thrown after external Ressources are touched, the database must keep the current step to enable a continue/cleanup afterwards.

I did not find a way to achieve autocommit or to disable rollback. I have read that just catching the Exception would not do the trick, since the transaction is already marked for rollback.

So which is a correct way to disable rollback and to commit every query as soon as possible? I do not want to disturb the rest of the application, so I would avoid

```
JPA.em().getTransaction().commit();
JPA.em().getTransaction().begin();
```

after every write.

Which way I can simply keep the written data?

Comment: JPA might not be the best solution for you, as it is meant for persisting changes to a many objects in one go.  When there is an exception, there is no real way to tell what in the context was pushed into the database and what wasn't, which is why the spec forces providers to rollback and have applications retry the transaction.  You might want to isolate your database transaction from the other processes so that they can be used and rolled back independently, allowing you to retry database operations in a new transaction without affecting the entire process.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. What a pity. Just my second little project with JPA and the second annoying limitation I find. :-( Since JPA gives no access to a JDBC Connection, I will have to store everything in an email in case of an Exception.

Comment: You can access the connection via the unwrap API http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager